# I am trying to execute the openCV code on Windows 8 it shows Not Responding Windows.

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, windows-8, mingw

I am trying to execute the openCV code on Windows 8 it shows Not Responding Windows. 
I'm using the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "!!!Hello World !!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
cvNamedWindow( "abc", 1 );
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "C:\\Users\\****\\Pictures\\123.jpg" );
 cvShowImage( "abc", img );
 while( 1 ) {
     if( cvWaitKey( 100 ) == 27 ) break;
   }

 cvDestroyWindow( "abc" );
   cvReleaseImage( &img );

return 0;
}
```

When i execute the above code i got the following Error:

Windows Not responding.

Other Information:

OS: Windows8
IDE : EClipse
openCV Vesion 2.4.0
c++ compiler : MinGW

Please let me know if more additional information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
bool stop = 0;
while( !stop) {
    if( cvWaitKey( 100 ) == 27 ) stop=1;
}
```

What happens in debug mode? Expand the if statement and put a cout << "exit"; in, add a break point and then step through. Find out where it stops responding.